# Django rest swagger can't read json api paths

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui

I am trying to document my API via the django-rest-swagger plugin but I have a problem.  The jsons have been created with my API paths and everything but swagger can't read them. I am getting this message:

```
fetching resource list: http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/api-docs/
```

I am using django-rest-swagger 0.3.4 and djangorestframework 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If the error you're seeing is:

```
Can't read swagger JSON from http://127.0.0.1:8000/doc/api-docs/
```

Check for a missing trailing slash in your `urls.py` for the `docs` root where you include the swagger urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    #          ^-- don't forget this
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It would have been impossible to debug this if it wasn't for your answer.